# Reactive programming that calls onComplete based on a set and then repeats

Tags: rx-java2

In ReactiveX, I have a series of events where I need to group the events into sets based on the event type and a unique ID.

So the series looks like this:

```
a1 a2 b1 c1 b2 c2 ...
```

and would like the onCompleted to be called based on the following sets

```
[a1, b1, c1]

[a2, b2, c2]
```

and repeat indefinitely for 3, 4, 5 ...

If a set takes too long to receive all the events, the onError should be called.

With [groupby](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html) it is possible to group the events by the id, and then use [and then when](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#AndThenWhen) to get the three events but it isn't clear from the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) how to use this along with a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy`, `flatMap` and `takeUntil` inside of `flatMap` to have the groups complete when the terminal value is discovered:

```
Observable.fromArray("a1 a2 b1 c1 b2 c2".split("\\s"))
.groupBy(v -> v.charAt(1))                            // <------------------
.flatMap(g -> g
               .takeUntil(v -> v.charAt(0) == 'c')    // <------------------
               .toList())
.subscribe(...)
```

Replace the functions pointed at with the grouping and end-detection function of your datatype.

Comment: To finish the answer ... a timeout applied to g will cause onError to be called if the time is elapsed as in `g.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).takeUntil(...)`